# Outputting dynamic variables

Tags: variables, coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-10, dynamic-variables

Why can I not make my textbox show only what the user has entered?

```
<cfinput
 type="text"
 name="firstname_#Add#"
 value="#form['firstname_#Add#']#"
>
```

I have also researched and tried changing to

```
<input
 type="text"
 name="firstname_#Add#"
 value="<cfoutput>#form['firstname_#Add#']#</cfoutput>"
>

 <cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
     <cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Add#"]="">
    <cfparam name="form['firstname_#Add#']" default="session.checkout.info.firstname_#Add#">
    </cfloop>
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
     <cfset errors = []>
    <cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
    <cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
    <cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Add#"]=form["firstname_#Add#"]>
    </cfloop>
```

Where am I going wrong? Instead of being blank it is showing the session variable (session.checkout.info.firstname_#Add#") then instead of saving it when the user hits a link back to that page it changes what they have entered back to (session.checkout.info.firstname_#Add#"). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend starting with Fiddler (a traffic inspection tool, invaluable for web devs!) to ensure that you are actually sending what you think you're sending and placing in the form scope.  You mention a session variable, but nothing in your provided code really helps us narrow the issue down.

Comment: How session comes in middle ?
Please elaborate your question. Are you not able to display dynamic value in textbox on page load ?

Comment: Has a form been submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling that `CFPARAM` to use the text "session...", not the value of "session...". This should get you what you want:

<cfparam name="form['firstname_' & Add]" default="#session['checkout.info.firstname_' & Add]#">

Comment: Hmm, are you  sure that the name value should be surrounded by #'s? Obviously the default value should, as you pointed out.

Comment: Eh, probably not. Removed them. I rarely use cfparam directly anymore.

Comment: Curiosity, what do you mean you "don't use CFPARAM directly anymore"? Not criticizing, just interested. Do you use a lot of isDefined/similar validation?

Comment: hmmm when I use that instead its throwing this error.. Element checkout.info.firstname_1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.MemorySessionScope.

Comment: @DB7 You're not declaring session.checkout.info.firstname_1. You can do that via a cfparam with a default value, or perhaps you're meaning to set it somewhere and it's not being set... <cfparam name="session.checkout.info.firstname_#Add#" default="0" type="numeric"> should be above the previous cfparam adrian provided.

Comment: @bracketsage I use ColdBox for CF development, which uses an Event object to contain most variables. That object has a paramValue() function to set defaults, which just abstracts CFPARAM.

Comment: value="#evaluate("session.checkout.info.firstname_#Add#")#"> .. is what I had to use to make it work

Comment: You shouldn't have to use evaluate() there. I'd avoid that like that plague. In fact, we've outlawed it in our coding standards.